# Templated Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

For some reason my compiler is getting a sigabrt fault at the "delete subtree" line when this is compiled. Am I doing something wrong?

```
template <typename T>
void BST<T>::clear(BTNode *subtree)
{
    if (subtree != nullptr)
    {
        clear(subtree->m_Left);
        clear(subtree->m_Right);
        delete subtree;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your end leafs are `nullptr`s, or that you invoke it on a valid node? Otherwise the function seems to be OK.

Comment: What does the BTNode destructor do?

Comment: Are you using any `assert` statements in your code?